# How to save the State of this Toggle Button(Heart) after application restart?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdp6X.png)

I tried SharedPreferences, but it didn't worked.
Why the toogle state is not saved ?

I am using RecyclerView where there is a Toggle Button.

Here is my onBindViewHolder() code :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final ToggleModel toggleModel = toggleModelList.get(position);

        if(toggleModel.isFavorite())
            holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(toggleModel.getToggled());
        else
            holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(toggleModel.getUntoglled());

        //Set title from model
        holder.textView.setText(toggleModel.getTitle());
        ((ViewHolder) holder).copybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "dfdfd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                cm.setText(holder.textView.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Copied :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.toggle_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("save",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (toggleModel.isFavorite) {
                    toggleModel.setFavorite(false);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "UNFavorited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("tgpref", false); // value to store
                    editor.apply();

                }
                else {
                    toggleModel.setFavorite(true);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Favorited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true); // value to store
                    editor.apply();
                    //Log.e("IN ELSE PART",editor.apply());
                }

                notifyItemChanged(position);

            }
        });
 }
```

Can Anyone Please provide your valuable Suggestions Please

Comment: Try with editor.commit() and check what it returns?

Comment: trying now, just a sec

Comment: not working !!!

Comment: How and where are you reading the value out of shared preferences?

Comment: If there is 'n' number of entries (I mean verse in your case) in the recycler view, I don't think to store the value of 'toggling' inside a preference as all the entries are pointed to boolean value 'tgpref' and its get overwritten each time. In this situation, I will suggest you to use Room DB for storage.

Comment: HOW TO USE ????

Comment: You can find the room docs here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Comment: If you still want to use shared preference, you can store the verse ids  (instead of favorite state) with proper delimiter in shared preference and compare the id from string data (retrieved from shared preference) while the binding views inside recycler view.

Comment: it is more recommended to use .apply instead of .commit.

Comment: @LidorIvanE.S  did it, but nothing worked as per the Question

Comment: you need it to be encrypted or not?